# Get Facebook Page Fan's Birthday To Send Birthday Greetings?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page

I was wondering if it would be possible to get a list of a Facebook Page fans and their birthday, then on their birthday have it post a birthday greeting on their wall? I want to do this without the use of a Facebook App and have it post directly from the Facebook Page to the users/fans wall (possibly using OpenGraph and PHP?). I just want to know if this can be done and what I should utilize in the Facebook API?

Comment: To post on a user's wall, you need `publish_stream` authorization from the user. Also, you will have to use a FB App for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Facebook graph to get the fans of a fan page?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2743937/using-facebook-graph-to-get-the-fans-of-a-fan-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get details about a fan or post to their timeline / wall without using an app. There are separate permissions required to achieve what you are trying to do, and none of these are possible without using an app, and getting the user to install the app (with the correct permissions).

Answer (score 0):

Use Facebook Ads and target your fan base only on their birthday. Facebook allows you to post the ad to fans but only on their birthdays. Click here for details

http://michaelbrandvold.com/blog/2011/01/2000-things-to-generate-20000-fans-wish-your-fans-a-happy-birthday/

Comment: Hi! It's always good to post the relevant quote/code from the article because, you know, resources on the web like to disappear. Then this answer will have less meaning that it has now.